# Is it possible to blacklist user form using telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new to do this kind of project. My goals is to build a telegram bot to forward user(s) message from the bot to a channel. Right now I'm facing that some users abuse to send junk message that disturbs a lot. So, is it possible to blacklist some user from using the bot?

My sourcecode is here [Go to GitHub](https://github.com/saucedbeacon/Telegram_Forwarder)

Answer (score 2):

Bots can't block users (like users can block bots), but you can choose to just not handle updates that come from a specific user id. What I usually do in such cases is to use a `telegram.ext.TypeHandler(telegram.Update, callback)` where `callback` looks something like

```
def callback(update, context):
    if update.effective_user and update.effective_user in blocked_users:
        # This stops any other handlers in higher groups from running   
        raise DispatcherHandlerStop
```

Then register it to a low group for the dispatcher (`dispatcher.add_handler(…, group=-1)`).
Please have a look at the docs of [`TypeHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.typehandler.html), [`DispatcherHandlerStop`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcherhandlerstop.html) and [`add_handler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html#telegram.ext.Dispatcher.add_handler) for more info :)

One way to keep track of the `blocked_users` is to store that list in `context.bot_data`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any native way to do that, however you can have a list of blocked users (preferably a separate JSON file for that extra modularity) and every time the bot is used, check if the user is in that list:

```
def start(update, context):
  if update.effective_user.id in blacklist:
    pass # or do whatever you want
```